# como puedo optimizar estos bucles en js?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un proyecto en desarrollo para la creación de solicitudes y tiene la función de mostrar el Status actual de la solicitud, tengo que mostrarlas es un Data Table con el ultimo status, tengo el siguiente codigo:

`

```
    var list_idHelpsSol = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 10] 
    var list_StatusSol = [[{"id_Sol": 1, "Type_Status": "enviado"}{"id_Sol": 1, "Type_Status": "enviado"}{"id_Sol": 1, "Type_Status": "enviado"}]]
    var list = []
        for (let i = 0; i < list_idHelpsSol.length; i++) {
            const id_sol = list_idHelpsSol[i];

            for (let i = 0; i < list_StatusSol.length; i++) {
                const id_status = list_StatusSol[i];
                if (id_sol == id_status["id_Sol"]) {

                    if (list.length) {// si la lista NO esta vacia, tonses tecorrera dicha lista en busca de una lista con un diccionario que tenga el mismo id_Sol
                        for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                            const lista_lista = list[i];

                            if (lista_lista[0] == id_sol) {
                                lista_lista.push( id_status["id_Sol"] )
                                lista_lista.push( id_status["Type_Status"] )
                            }

                            list.push( [ id_status["id_Sol"], id_status["Type_Status"] ]   )

                        }
                        
                    }
                    else{
                        list.push( [ id_status["id_Sol"], id_status["Type_Status"] ]   )
                        
                        
                    }
                    
                }

            }
```

`

Comment: Primero corrige tu código y haz que funcione y luego piensa en la optimización.

Comment: como puedo corregirlo?